# Reading the correct directory

Tags: c#, directory

I've tested the code and the directory gets the correct input, but for some reason it can't find it.  Is there something I'm missing why I can't find any directory?

Here is my code pretty simplistic as of right now.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string fileName;
    string dirName;    

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dirName = textBox1.Text;
        fileName = textBox2.Text;

        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(dirName))
        {               
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
            {                    
                System.IO.File.Delete(fileName);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Directory or File Name");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you consider to be "the correct input"?

Comment: You arent combining the directory name and filename, what are the values? I would use something like Path.Combine(dirName, fileName)

Comment: What is the value of `dirName`? What about `fileName`?

Comment: It doesn't make sense.  You assigned whatever value you receive from the textBoxes to the dirName and fileName.  Did you type the path to the directory and the file on the textboxes?

Comment: Right, the value comes from the text boxes.

Comment: @BrodyHerrmann review the Remarks section here (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists(v=vs.110).aspx) and see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

That's because I guess you're passing the directory path by an input control in this way "C:/examplePath/" and it should be declared in this way "C:\\examplePath" because the escape characters, and probably you'll get another error further because when you're asking for a file's existence, you must to declare it concatenating directory path plus filename (and its extension).

so the final string should be like this "c:\\exampleDir\\examplefile.ext"

or simply you should try:

```
dirName = string.Format("@{0}", textBox1.Text);
fullPathFile = string.Format("{0}/{1}", dirName, textBox2.Text);
```

And then you use "fullPathFile" instead of "fileName" variable.

Don't forget to debug your application for making sure what's the string values.

Comment: This wouldnt apply to text entered from the ui, it would only apply to text coded in at design time. Also, forward slashes (/) are ok and dont need to be escaped. Also, you manually combine the paths, using the Path static helpers simplifies your code no end!:)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, it appears fileName and dirName come from two different textbox controls. And you also dont do any sort of combining the file path (or so it appears). So when you call Directory.Exists() it makes sense that this would work but it can't find the file. When you use File.Exists() you need to pass in not only the file name but also the directory where its located. To do this use the Path.Combine() method.

```
if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(dirName))
{
    string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(dirName, fileName);

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
    }

    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Directory or File Name");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense.